# How to enable Hyper-V on a Windows machine?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm new to Visual Studio, and I just downloaded the Xamarin package over the weekend. The very first time I ran the Android Emulator, it seemed to work fine. (This was simply running the "Hello World" base-script. Then when I opened the emulator again, it began having Deployment errors.
[Deploy Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXmM7.png)

Pressing Yes, yields no results. After some research of my own, I believe that the issue may be because Hyper-V is not running. Enabling it should be simple, but i have tried a few different methods and cannot seem to get it to run. One way I tried was via Powershell: [Powershell Feature Name Unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IQQk.png)

Having tried that, I tried to enable it manually via settings: [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sik4x.png)
To my understanding, there should be a few different folders here called "Hyper-V" or something to that effect on top of Hypervision Platform folder. Is this why my emulator isn't running, because I don't have access to the Hyper-V folders, or could something be wrong in Vis Studio itself? Like I said, I'm very new to this software and workflow so any trouble shooting ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What Windows SKU do you have?  Hyper-V is only available on Pro and above

Comment: Ah, I am on Windows 10 Home, does this only work on Windows 7, or is there an equivalent Pro for 10?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33557.windows-10-editions-skus-and-features.aspx

Comment: Thank you this is great! Thanks for such quick responses!